# Find word in a text tath can be start with non alfanumeric character

Tags: regex, non-alphanumeric

I need to find word ( I know it) in a text of any lenght, like the following.

```
My text is very beautyfull. Yours  $text is very bautyfull. Their #text, is very beautyfull
```

`#` and `$` are only sample. I can have any non-alphnumerical character

I have found the following regex:

```
(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])\Q<word>\E(?=$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])
```

tath work very well if i search `#text` or `$text`, but when i search only `text` it match all occurrences (three in example below)  instead only one occurrence `text`.
Is there a way to do this with regex?

Answer (score 0):

Add `#` and `$` to the first negated char class which was present inside the positive lookbehind. So that it won't match the string `text` which was preceded by `#` or `$` or `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9`

```
(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z0-9$#])\Qtext\E(?=$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zB2bY3/2)

Comment: or you could simply use this `(?<=^|[^\S$#])\Qtext\E(?=$|[^\S])`

Comment: `#` and `$`are only simple, I can have other characters . I need something like `\b` that also work with non-alphanumerical characters.

Comment: yep, but you need to remove the `\Q\E`.. i think you want to achieve without removing `\Q\E`

Comment: yep, because if i need to find `$text`, `$` is interpreted as regex command without `\Q...\E`